# Sync browser windows across multiple devices?

Tags: ios, browser, responsive-design, synchronization

My graphic design portfolio show is coming up soon and I was wondering if there was a way I could sync up an iMac, iPad and an iPhone so that when you click on a link on any one of them the link would open on all 3 devices simultaneously. The reason for this is I will have some responsive web design examples up and I think it'd be a neat effect for the users, so you wouldn't have to click on any given link on all 3 devices separately. Makes sense? Not sure if there's already an answer out there but I'm not having any luck searching for it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: are these files being hosted from a server? or just a filesystem? are you looking for an all-in-one software solution or do you want to do this with programming?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but people out there looking for solution's, should check out

https://github.com/shakyShane/browser-sync

best of all it's free.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a server side application that does this, but to get it for the clients themselves would require some plugin for the browser. I don't know how Apple handles plugins for safari, but you may be able to do it in chrome. Either way, you still need a central location that keeps track of what pages you request. It wouldn't take all that long if you controlled the site the pages were hosted on, otherwise you are going to have to write a browser plugin and a server application.

Comment: There could be apps for apples devices that do this, but I am not aware of any.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I was hoping there was a plug-in or something. I don't program. Oh and I just want this to work at my portfolio show, not for the clients.

Comment: Oh sorry, when I say clients, I mean in the client-server model.